# Angular cannot add type to options object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 8 and in a component I have a variable declared:

```
 data = [];
```

This in the method I try to assign data to this.data above

```
 async mytest() {
    await Filesystem.appendFile({
      path: 'dat.csv',
      data: this.data // Error Here
    });
  }
```

When I add this.data I get:

```
  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Evidently `appendFile` expects the `data` prop of its argument to be a `string`, whereas you're suppyling an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign an array or object to `data` property it needs to be converted to a string. You could use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
 async mytest() {
    await Filesystem.appendFile({
      path: 'dat.csv',
      data: JSON.stringify(this.data)
    });
  }
```

Although I'm not sure if a stringified array is what you're going after.